# Fetching net use details

Tags: powershell

I am using `net use` to get the Windows mount path and drive.

```
PS C:\Users\jagg> net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\ITHANSJJA001.ABC.COM\opmas$
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

I would like to fetch the drive and mount path detail using PowerShell command. Is there any way to get it using only PowerShell?

Comment: You're looking for [`Get-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: No, Net use only. But want to fetch the values of drive and mount path. In my case drive is Y

Comment: `Get-PSDrive` provides you with all the information you're looking for. If you elect to ignore the solution to your problem you're on your own. Have fun.

Comment: but with this command how can I say which drive is mounted or mapped?

Comment: Also how u get field values? When I use this command  it shows 6 columns how can I get particular col value?

Comment: Hmm... I was pretty certain that `Get-PSDrive` shows the remote path in the `DisplayRoot` property, but that doesn't seem to always be the case. In that case use `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkConnection` (which is mentioned in the `Get-PSDrive` documentation I linked to).

Comment: Select a particular set of properties with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-3.0): `... | Select-Object LocalName, RemoteName`. Access the value of a single property via dot-access: `$obj.RemoteName`. For general help on working with PowerShell objects and their properties please consult a PowerShell tutorial of your choosing.

Comment: This was also very useful, thanks for your timely help and sorry for the delay in responding ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be confused about what powershell is able to do. [*grin*]

however, here are two ways to get the info you seem to want. the 1st parses the output of `net use` while the 2nd uses `Get-PSDrive` to get that same info natively.

```
(net use) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' |
    Select-String -SimpleMatch '\\' |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Status', 'DriveLetter', 'MountPath', 'Network' |
    Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, MountPath

''

Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    # the 4 slashes are 2 regex-escaped slashes
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayRoot -match '\\\\'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DriveLetter = '{0}:' -f $_.Name
            MountPath = $_.DisplayRoot
            }
        }
```

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: In my German locale the `net use` Status sometimes leaves only **ONE** space between the columns. A workaround is an enhanced RE `(net use) -replace '\s{2,}| (?=[A-Z]:)', ','` which also replaces the one space followed by a letter and a colon.

Comment: @LotPings - thank you for that info. i have never tried `net use` in any other locale. [*grin*]